# NSDate with no time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have written the following method:

```
- (NSDate *)stringToDate:(NSString *)dateString
{
    // Convert string to date
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:tz];
    NSDate * date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 00:00:00", dateString]];

    return dateOnly;
}
```

When I call this with just a date such as 11/1/2013 or 11/13/2013 I get 2013-11-01 04:00:00 +0000 and 2013-11-13 05:00:00 +0000.

If I set a breakpoint on the return the date appears right, but if I break at in the calling function after this call, the date is returned with the time.

How come my time is not always 0. Can anyway tell me what is wrong in my function?

Thank you

UPDATE:

The input string is as follows: 11/1/2013 and 11/13/2013

Comment: Can you put the string that you are trying to convert into your question.

Comment: Is there is mistake in your post? You are passing date string of 2013-11-01 and yet your date formatter is Monthy/day/year ... or did I miss something?

Comment: Typo, sorry, i updated post

Comment: I have made many clock and calendar apps and vikingosegundo answer is correct, you will always have a time that will in UTC/GMT time. System is smart enough to know that your 00:00:00 means 12:00am for whatever date you set it. So don't get hanged up on the time part

Comment: Yes, I understand what he is saying, however, it does not make sense, I call it two times, one with 11/1/2013 and the next time with 11/13/2013, both have 00:00:00 set for hours, minutes and seconds but the result is different.

Comment: Why would daylight savings time come into play for a date that is only 12 days apart?

Comment: see my answer for that. the switch is just between those two dates.

Comment: OMG, duh, I see, DST is 11/3/2013, I get it. Ok, so can I ignore that?  I am trying to compare NSDates when I do my comparison fails because of the time part.

Comment: I guess i would be able to always use GMT as the timezone, right?  Would that make the time always be 0 if I create the NSDate that way?  Does that make sense?

Comment: see my answer. create time that is save from dst changes.

Comment: and watch the linked video! it covers more subtle pitfalls.

Comment: Got it, I will definetly look at the video... thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSDate is a point in time. It will always have a time component.
And if not printed as a string form a NSDateFormatter, the Date and time will always be the one of UTC/GMT.

---

The format and the date string must fit.

```
NSString *dateString = @"11/1/2013";
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy"];
```

---

The one hour apart comes from the Daylight saving time. Till November, 3rd 2013 New York has Summer time. http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=179

---

> Ok, so can I ignore that? I am trying to compare NSDates when I do my comparison fails because of the time part

You should create dates with with a time during the day — i.e. noon — to be save of DST mess and compare those. Use NSComponents for that.

---

A must-see for any iOS/Cocoa-Developer: the fantastic [WWDC 2011 Video "Session 117 - Performing Calendar Calculations"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=117).